# Hint on how to prove $\zeta ( 2) =\pi ^{2}/6$ using the complex Fourier series of $f(x)=x$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, fourier-analysis, fourier-series, special-functions

I know how to prove $\zeta (2)=\pi ^{2}/6$ by using the *trigonometric* Fourier series expansion of $x^{2}/4$. How can one prove the same result using the *complex* Fourier series of $f(x)=x$ for $0\leq x\leq 1$? Any suggestion?

Comment: @VFG: Did you calculate the Fourier coefficients? 
Can you see any similarity to $\zeta(2)$? How can you manipulate the Fourier series?

Comment: AD: Yes. One of the difficulties I have is dealing with a complex rather than a trigonometric Fourier series.

Comment: I believe you are supposed to be using Parseval's identity.

Comment: Qiaochu Yuan: That is a good hint, thanks. Anyhow could you please elaborate a little bit?

Comment: I just want to point out this process can be generalized to give you $\zeta(2n)$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$.  In this case dealing with $[0,1]$ is simpler than $[-\pi,\pi]$, so $f(z)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}c_ne^{2\pi inz}$ where $c_n=\int_0^1 f(z)e^{-2\pi inz}dz$.  The coefficients of $f(x)=x^{2n}$ will give you $\zeta(2n)$.  However, if you instead use the Bernoulli polynomials, the integration by parts turns out much nicer (the $uv|_0^1$ terms all go away). http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_polynomials

Comment: @Americo Tavares:  The Fourier coefficients of $f(x)=x$ actually only involve $\frac{1}{n}$, so it doesn't quite give you $\zeta(2)$.  However, Parseval's Theorem says $\int_0^1 |f(z)|^2dz=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}|c_n|^2$.  The left hand side is easy enough to evaluate, and the right hand side will give you the $\frac{1}{n^2}$ you need (note that $c_0=0$, so the sum doesn't blow up on you).

Comment: @Riley E: Thanks a lot for your explanations. A few weeks ago I computed the
trigonometric Fourier series for $f(x)=x^{2p},x\in \left[ -\pi ,\pi \right] $

$$\frac{2\pi ^{2p}}{2p+1}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }a_{n,2p}\cdot \cos nx,$$

where 

$$a_{n,2p}=\frac{2}{\pi }\int_{0}^{\pi }x^{2p}\cos nx\;\mathrm{d}x.$$

For $x=\pi $, it gives

$$\pi ^{2p}=\frac{2\pi ^{2p}}{2p+1}+\frac{2}{\pi }\sum_{n=1}^{\infty
}a_{n,2p}\cdot \cos n\pi .$$

 ...

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/374221/fourier-series-of-fx-x and http://math.stackexchange.com/a/324158

Comment: @MartinSleziak Thanks for both links, in particular the first one!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the definition:

Say $f$ is defined on $[-\pi, \pi]$.

If $f(z) = \sum_{-\infty}^{\infty} {c_{n} e^{inz}}$

then

$c_{n} = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}{f(z)e^{-inz}} dz$

If you put $f(z) = z$, can you work out what $c_{n}$ turns out to be?

To integrate, you can try integration by parts.

Comment: @VFG: I am curious though, was this homework? It is ok to ask I believe, as long as you say it is homework and show what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 2):

Extending off from Aryabhatta answer:

---

**For our situation**:  We have $f(x)=x ~~~{\text{ for }} 0\leq x\leq 1$

$2L=1,\Rightarrow L=\frac{1}{2}$

So restating we have:

$f(x) = \displaystyle\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} {c_{n} e^{inx}}, \text{ where }c_{n} = \displaystyle\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\frac{1}{2}}^{\frac{1}{2}}{f(x)e^{-inx}} ~\mathrm{d}x,~~~~~~n=0,~\pm 1,~\pm 2, \cdots~ $

$
\Rightarrow~~ c_{n} = \displaystyle\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\frac{1}{2}}^{\frac{1}{2}}{xe^{-inx}}~\mathrm{d}x
$

After integrating the *complex Fourier coefficient* we see that we get the following:

$\Rightarrow~~~~\displaystyle c_n=i\left(\frac{\cos(\frac{n}{2})}{2\pi n}-\frac{\sin(\frac{n}{2})}{\pi n^2}\right),~~~\text{for }n \in \mathbb{R}$

Lastly plugging back $c_n$ into $f(x)$ we then get our desired result for $n=0,~\pm 1,~\pm 2, \cdots~$.

Please update if you see any mistakes with any of the work. It has been quite some time since I work with Fourier Series and went off from my head. Feel free to edit mistakes as necessary if willing.

Thanks.

Comment: It seems strange that you have included Aryabhatta's answer word for word within your own.

Comment: @Jonas: His really was not needed to be restated, I was just putting so people could follow along without having to scroll back and forth between the two. His was just for some generic interval as I was trying to ask the question at hand. Could remove if seems strange. That is why I added the note above before proceeding.

Answer (score 1):

This is not related but you would like to see this article: A Short Proof of ζ (2) = π2/6 T.H. Marshall American Math monthly April 2010.