# Fourier Series of $f(x) = x$

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series

I am having trouble finding the complex Fourier series of $f(x) = x$ and using that complex series to find 1)the real Fourier series of $f(x)$ and 2) the complex and real Fourier series of $h(x) = x^2$.

$$
     f(x) = x , -\pi < x < \pi
$$

$$
    f(x) = \sum_{n = -\infty}^{\infty} C_n e^{-inx} 
$$

where

$$
    C_n = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} f(x) e^{-inx} dx
$$

Attempt:   for $n \neq 0$:

$$
    C_n = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} xe^{-inx} dx   
$$

$$
    C_n = \frac{1}{2\pi} \left[ -\frac{x}{in}e^{-inx}  \right]_{-\pi}^{\pi} - \frac{1}    {2\pi}\left[ \frac{1}{i^2 n^2} e^{-inx} \right]_{-\pi}^{\pi}
$$

$$
    C_n =  -\frac{1}{2in} \left( e^{-in\pi} + e^{in\pi} \right) + \frac{1}{2\pi n^2} \left( e^{-in\pi} - e^{in\pi} \right) 
$$

$$
      C_n = \frac{i}{n}(-1)^n - \frac{i}{\pi n^2 } \sin(n \pi )
$$

$$
   \Rightarrow f = \sum_{n = -\infty}^{\infty} \left( \frac{i}{n}(-1)^n - \frac{i}{\pi n^2 } \sin(n \pi )\right)e^{-inx}
$$

Is this $f(x)$ correct? How would I get the real and complex series of $h(x)$ from this? I know to get the real series of f(x) we normally can break the sum into

$$
  f =  \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \left[ \left( \frac{i}{n}(-1)^n - \frac{i}{\pi n^2 } \sin(n \pi )\right)e^{-inx} +  \left( \frac{i}{-n}(-1)^{-n} + \frac{i}{\pi n^2 } \sin(n \pi )\right)e^{inx} \right]
$$

which gives

$$
   f(x)  = -\frac{ 2\sin(nx) }{n}\left[ (-1)^n + \frac{\sin(n \pi)}{\pi n}\right]
$$

so the real series of $h(x)$ could possibly be computed by evaluating the lengthy $f^2$ expression but is this the only way? How do I then evaluate the complex Fourier series of $h$.

UPDATE :

$\sin(n \pi) = 0$ ( Don't know why I couldn't notice this before) so,

$$
  f(x) = \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} -\frac{2(-1)^n \sin(nx) }{n}
$$

notice that

$$
  h(x) = 2 \int_0^x f(\gamma) d\gamma
$$

$$
 h = 2 \int_0^x \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} -\frac{2(-1)^{n} \sin(n \gamma) }{n} d\gamma
$$

$$
 h = \int_0^x \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} -\frac{4(-1)^{n} \sin(n \gamma) }{n} d\gamma
$$

$$
 h = \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{4(-1)^{n} ( \cos(nx) - 1 )}{n^2}
$$

Constant term is

$$
   \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{4(-1)^{n+1}}{n^2}
$$

Don't know how this can be shown to equaivalent to $\frac{\pi ^2}{3}$

Comment: Regardless of whether this is right or not, you might want to pay some attention to the value of $\sin n\pi$ when $n$ is an integer, and also be a little more careful about what happens when $n=0$

Comment: Regarding your last sentence see my edit.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Note that $\sin(n\pi)=0$, so your coefficients are simply
$$C_n = \frac{i}{n}(-1)^n,\quad n\neq 0$$ which results in

$$f(x) = -2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{n}\sin(nx)$$

Just a hint concerning the coefficients $D_n$ of $h(x)$: First, note that $D_0\neq 0$ because $h(x)\ge 0$. Second, note that $h(x)$ is even, so its series will only have cosine terms. The cosine coefficients will turn out to be

$$a_n = 4 \frac{(-1)^n}{n^2},\quad n=1,2,\ldots$$
Try to verify this result yourself.

Comment: Managed to find a_n, but how do I find the constant term of the h(x) expression?

Comment: $D_0 = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}h(x)dx=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi}x^2 dx=\frac{\pi^2}{3}$.

Comment: The value will be  $D_0 = \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{4(-1)^{n+1}}{n^2}$ but is there a way to continue from there to evaluate the actual constant?

Comment: Thank you! I don't know why I didn't think of that

Comment: The best way is to equate this sum with the integral in my previous comment. If you want to try to directly evaluate the sum, check the Basel Problem: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basel_problem

Comment: I didn't see you edited you original comment to show how to compute the solution from h(x), I think your solution is good enough, no need to go to bessel problems.

Answer (score 3):

An *alternative* approach.

1. Since the Fourier *trigonometric* series expansion is given by
   $$
   \begin{eqnarray*}
   f(x) &=&\frac{a_{0}}{2}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }\left( a_{n}\cos nx+b_{n}\sin
   nx\right)  \\
   a_{n} &=&\frac{1}{\pi }\int_{-\pi }^{\pi }f(x)\cos nx,\qquad n=0,1,2,\ldots 
   \\
   b_{n} &=&\frac{1}{\pi }\int_{-\pi }^{\pi }f(x)\sin nx,\qquad n=1,2,\ldots, 
   \end{eqnarray*}\tag{1}
   $$
   we conclude that for $f(x)=x$, $-\pi < x < \pi$, we have $a_{n}=0$  and
   $$
   \begin{equation*}
   b_{n}=\frac{1}{\pi }\int_{-\pi }^{\pi }x\sin nxdx=2\frac{\sin \pi n-\pi
   n\cos \pi n}{\pi n^{2}}.
   \end{equation*}\tag{2}
   $$
   So for $x\in]-\pi,\pi[$
   $$
   \begin{equation*}
   f(x)=x=2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{\sin \pi n-\pi n\cos \pi n}{\pi n^{2}}\sin nx
   =\dots
   \end{equation*}\tag{3}
   $$ For $x=\pm\pi$ the series $(3)$ converges to $0$.
2. For $h(x)=x^{2}$ a similar computation in [this MSE answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/8378/752) (or in [this blog post](http://problemasteoremas.wordpress.com/2012/08/24/dois-metodos-para-calcular-%CE%B62/) of mine, in Portuguese) yields
   $$
   \begin{equation*}
   f(x)=x^{2}=\frac{\pi ^{2}}{3}+4\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }\left( (-1)^{n}\frac{1}{n^{2}}
   \cos nx\right) ,\qquad x\in \left[ -\pi ,\pi \right]. \tag{4} 
   \end{equation*}
   $$

ADDED: Answer to

> Constant term is
>   $$ \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{4(-1)^{n+1}}{n^2} $$
>
> Don't know how this can be shown to equivalent to $\frac{\pi ^2}{3}$

[Dirichlet eta function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_eta_function) (alternating zeta function) $\eta (s)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n^{s}}$ can be expressed in terms of the [Riemann zeta function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function) $\zeta (s)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{1}{n^{s}}$
$$
\begin{equation*}
\eta (s)=(1-2^{1-s})\zeta (s)
\end{equation*}
$$

Since $\zeta (2)=\dfrac{\pi ^{2}}{6}$, we have that $\eta (2)=\dfrac{1}{2}
\zeta (2)=\dfrac{\pi ^{2}}{12}$ and

$$4\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n^{2}}=4\eta (2)=\frac{\pi ^{2}}{3}.$$

Comment: I think you missed a factor 4 before the sum in (4).

Comment: @Matt Thanks! Fixed.

Comment: I was looking to compute h(x) = x^2 from f(x) and not directly, but thanks for giving me the final solution, it gives me something to work towards.

Comment: @KillaKem OK. You can verify that every function $f$ of the form $f(x)=x^{2p}$, $p=1,2,\dots$ can be extended into a trigonometric series, which can be used to evaluate $\zeta(2p)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty 1/n^{2p}$.

Comment: I am a bit confused about when we use $ f(x)= \text{series}$ and $ f(x)\text{near equal to series}$. If $ f(x)=x$ needs to be expressed in its fourier series in $ [-\pi,\pi]$, what do we write? $ f(x)=\text{series}$ or $ f(x) \text{near equal to series}$

Comment: @ManjoyDas To define a Fourier  trigonometric series the function $f(x)$ should be periodic. Then, this series converges to $f(x)=x$ in the interval $]-\pi,\pi[$. Outside this interval it converges to a periodic function shifted by $2k\pi$ for $k\in\mathbb{Z}$. In the upper and lower interval limits the series converges to $\frac{f(x^+)+f(x^-)}{2}$.

Comment: Then should I check the following things?  i) whether the series converges for all $ x\in (-\pi,\pi)$.   ii) whether it converges   at $  x=\pm \pi$   iii) whether it converges at any discontinuity in $ \left[-\pi,\pi\right ]$, if exists. Failing any one of the above would give no such series for $ f(x)$?      And the second thing is what happens in case of open interval? I mean if the given interval is $(-\pi,\pi)$?